# IQueryable WebAPI service: why do I need to call .ToList()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, wcf-web-api

I inherited this code from a developer who left last week.  His code is based on the article:
["Restful WCF / EF POCO / UnitOfWork / Repository / MEF"](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/EntArch1.aspx).

This method works (when I browse to http://myapp/myservice/Returns):

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Returns")]
public IQueryable<ReturnSnapshot> GetReturnSnapshots()
{
    using (UnitOfWork)
    {
        ReturnSnapshotsRepository.EnrolInUnitOfWork(UnitOfWork);
        return ReturnSnapshotsRepository.FindAll().ToList().AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

but won't the `ToList()` will cause the whole table to be pulled from the repository?  We'll have 500K+ rows in production.

I thought I could change the last line to this:

```
return ReturnSnapshotsRepository.FindAll();
```

as `FindAll` returns IQueryable.  However, my change breaks the service, which now craps out with an HTTP 12152 error.

What should I be doing?

Comment: What's an "HTTP 12152 error"?

Comment: ERROR_WINHTTP_INVALID_SERVER_RESPONSE 12152 The server response cannot be parsed. -- Starting with Windows Server 2003, and Windows XP with SP2, the maximum amount of header data WinHTTP accepts in an HTTP response is 64K, by default. If the server HTTP response contains more that 64K of total header data, WinHTTP fails the request with an ERROR_WINHTTP_INVALID_SERVER_RESPONSE error.

Comment: Why do you dispose your unit-of-work before executing the query? That doesn't look right to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to return an `IQueryable<T>` from a WCF Web API REST service. I suspect the using block is causing your problem because the UnitOfWork is being disposed as soon as you return from this method but before the actual database query can be executed. Adding `ToList()` solves that problem but, as you pointed out, does so by loading everything into memory first so is less than ideal.

Comment: Perfecto.  Well, at first glance anyway  :)  I got rid of the unnecessary `using`, and the `ToList()`, and now the service works as expected.  SQLProfiler shows that deferred execution is happening, i.e. it is honouring `$top=1` rathering than pulling in the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it can be exposed over WCF, this may explain further

[Expose IQueryable Over WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291370/expose-iqueryable-over-wcf-service)