# WCF return type is object

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4

I have a  WCF method:

```
public IQueryable<AmenitySummary> GetAmenities(string searchTerm)
```

Now, `AmenitySummary` is defined thus

```
[DataContract]
public class AmenitySummary
{
    [DataMember]
    public int AmenityId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Amenity { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LowerCaseAmenity { get; set; }
}
```

In my client side solution I have a project in which I call this method.  The problem is that the signature in the Reference.cs file is this

```
public object GetAmenities(string searchTerm) {
   return base.Channel.GetAmenities(searchTerm);
}
```

How comes?  Why isn't the return type `IQueryable<AmenitySummary>`?  What am I missing?

Not only that, but when I try to use `AmenitySummary` on the client side I can't do it as it's not recognised.  I think this is linked.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IQueryable is not serialiable without specific references (see svcutil.exe /references).

Otherwise use a WCF DataService (OData) or return an array of AmenitySummary from the service. In the later case you can convert the array to an IQuaryable instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of `IQueryable`. You probably need to expose it too.

See this post:
[Expose IQueryable Over WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291370/expose-iqueryable-over-wcf-service)